# Ubuntu 14.04.1 install on Areca ARC-1883i - kernel detects partitions, installer sees no disks

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, raid, partitioning

I have a strange one here - when installing the kernel load detects my RAID controller and looking in the F4 debug screen, I can see it also detects the two volumes there.

When I come to the part in the installer to detect disks, it says "No disk drive was detected."

Furthermore, I have compiled the latest arcmsr kernel module; I use the F2 shell to unload the installer module and load my own from USB - which happens successfully - but still no disks are detected.

I know my kernel module is successful as looking at the F4 debug output, I see the RAID card correctly identified, and the two volumes are listed correctly as sd*.

lspci also identifies my RAID card correctly.

But again - when I "detect disks" it says none were found.

I am quite perplexed by this, and do not know how to proceed.

I should add, I used http://www.3dinfluence.com/blog/installing-ubuntu-server-unsupported-raid-controller as a guide on how to do this, as they seem to have had a very similar issue.

Please advise.

Thanks!

Viv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED!!!!!

Turns out the controller created the array volumes with write-protection on, so the installer detected the disks, but marked them as unusable.

I found this out by running fdisk from the installer debug console, and it told me that the filesystems were read-only. I then found the setting on the controller and disabled it.

I have a running install now! :-)